# Can files in the cache directory be deleted at any time?

Tags: android

The [documentation for Context.getCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()) says that "the system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device", and lists a few criteria for which files will be deleted first. My question is, are there any guarantees about when files will be *kept* that an application can rely on? For example, is it the case that files won't be deleted if the application is running and has the file open?

I suspect that the answer is that there are no guarantees, and the files can disappear at any time, but I couldn't find any confirmation about that.

Bonus question: is the answer different for the external cache directory, as returned by [Context.getExternalCacheDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalCacheDir())?

Comment: If a file is open it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the files present in the cache directory are deleted. the Android OS will always delete older files first, as reported by `File.lastModified()`. The Android OS will prioritise the deletion order of cache files via a special Quota function. If the total size of all files in the cache directory exceeds bytes returned by [`StorageManager.getCacheQuotaBytes(java.util.UUID)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getCacheQuotaBytes(java.util.UUID)), your app will be first whose cache files will be deleted when the system needs additional space. If this quota doesn't exceed, then your app will be at last sort (have the least chance) that its cache files would be deleted.

There is a better option than a cache directory, If you want to store files, you can use [`File.getDir(String name,  int mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int)). This directory will not be deleted unless the user clears storage. If the user clears storage, then the app will reset itself. Thus, when the user opens it again, it will run from the start.

If you want to store preferences then, SharedPreferences is the best option to go with. you can store tons of key-value pairs. Check out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Android OS will always start to remove the file's based on the `lastModified()`. It means the file you're already using. It will be the last file to delete (which makes this an edge case of losing the file at that moment).
But, In case you want to rely on the file. I would suggest using the `app_data` folder.

```
getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).path
```

The file will remain there as long as you need and you can delete the file when you want.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we all know that if a file is opened in the Application itself then that file is being used and is locked technically. So, if the OS tries to delete that file, it won't be able to do it.

Once, your app releases the file, that file is stored in the cache and will be deleted if the app is not frequently used.

So, the verdict is "Yes, the files will be deleted"